# Prove that $2^{9693}-1$ divisible by $7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that $2^{9693}-1$ divisible by $7$, by more than one way.

my try... that, the power divisible by $3$ so it's divisible by $7$ like $2^3,2^6,2^{12}$ and I think it's wrong.

Comment: Without mod arithmetic: $(2^{3})^{3231}-1^{3231}=(2^3-1)((2^{3})^{3230}+(2^{3})^{3229}+\cdots+2^3+1)$.

Answer (score 6):

One has $2^3=8\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and so $2^{9693}=\left(2^3\right)^{3231}\equiv 1\pmod 7$ and so $2^{9693}-1$ is divisible by $7$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

**Claim:** For any $n\in\mathbb N$, $2^{3n}-1$ is divisible by $7$.

*Proof:* Induction. For $n=1$, $2^{3\times 1}-1=7$. Now suppose that the claim is true for $1,2,\ldots,n$. Observe that 
\begin{align*}
2^{3(n+1)}-1=2^{3n+3}-1=2^{3n}\times 2^3-1=8\times 2^{3n}-1=8\times 2^{3n}-8+7=8\times(2^{3n}-1)+7.
\end{align*}
By the induction hypothesis, $2^{3n}-1$ is divisible by $7$, and thus so is $8\times(2^{3n}-1)$. Divisibility by $7$ is preserved by the addition of the extra term $7$. Therefore, $2^{3(n+1)}-1$ is divisible by $7$ and the proof is complete. $\quad\blacksquare$

Now apply the claim for $n=3\mathrm,231$.